# how to connect an android application to MySQL database?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application,and I have create a MySQL database in my computer,and I want to know how can I get the information in android application from the database ?

Comment: Check out this tutorial, however, your question is quite broad, and there are many ways to accomplish what you are trying to do. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

Answer (score 1):

i think that the best way is to expose an api (for example Rest Api) to access to your database.
So, from your app you'll call http://your-local-ip/insert and on your computer (server) you'll "catch" this call to "do what you want to do"